# Identity within TOR Browser

Tags: browsers

Before I updated, the browser would tell me where I was logging on from:  Germany, France and such. Now it only gives an IP address. I travel extensively and often require an identity from the US and now it's very difficult to tell where I am connecting through. Is there any way to address this?

Comment: No, your connection will always bounce around. If you need a static IP, try a US VPN and run Openvpn from Ubuntu.

Comment: why you don't use the [`ExitNodes`-"tag"](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en) in the [torrc file](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#torrc) to just include US exit nodes? -- so you don't have to check the country or ip anyway...!